# Quel est le sens du proverbe « Les pauvres ont la santé, les riches les remèdes » ?

Tags: sens, proverbes

> Les pauvres ont la santé, les riches les remèdes.

J'ai rencontré ce proverbe dans un livre sur le système de santé camerounais,* où il sert d'épigraphe.

* Baleba, Aubin Nino. Le système de santé camerounais entre décentralisation et globalisation: Réflexions sur un système de santé qui se cherche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il semble que les explications soient rares. J'en trouve une seule mais elle ne semble pas très satisfaisante.

> [Proverbes et dictons de France et leurs équivalents russes](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Proverbes_et_dictons_de_France_et_leurs/gtRvDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=Les+pauvres+ont+la+sant%C3%A9,+les+riches+les+rem%C3%A8des.&pg=PA134&printsec=frontcover) Constatation pleine de philosophie. La santé est essentielle et prime sur la richesse.

Il me semble que cela est plus plausible, mais hélas je ne réussis pas à dénicher une confirmation.
À en juger par une certaine philosophie populaire, qui croit en l'adéquation  de la bonne  santé et d'une vie au travail ([Le travail c'est la santé](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5VyRmrN0-Q)), et comme le pauvre est sensé  travailler d'une façon qui procure beaucoup  d'exercice  alors  que ce n'est pas le cas du riche, le pauvre aurait la santé du fait de son travail alors qu'elle manquerait au riche, mais en retour ce dernier aurait les moyens de se soigner alors que le pauvre ne les a pas.

Answer (score 1):

Voici comment je comprends ce proverbe :

*Les pauvres ont la santé* : Les pauvres n'ont que ça. Ils n'ont pas le loisir d'être malades. Ils sont donc « condamnés » à avoir la santé.

*Les riches (ont) les remèdes* : Les riches ont accès à la médecine et aux soins.